# System.ValueTuple exception

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0, dll

System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly "System.ValueTuple, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" or one of its dependencies. The definition of the assembly manifest found does not match the reference to the assembly.

Why I am getting this error?. My Project different module of different nuget version. That's why I added it is app.config.Still I am getting these errors

```
<assemblybinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentassembly>
    <assemblyidentity name="System.ValueTuple" publickeytoken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral"></assemblyidentity>
    <bindingredirect oldversion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.0" newversion="4.0.2.0"></bindingredirect>
  </dependentassembly>
</assemblybinding>
```

Comment: XML is case-sensitive. Your app.config snippet is in all lowercase